# Flipping Item Images inside GridView

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm fairly new to Windows 8 Modern UI Apps and I would like to know how I can flip tile images (ones located inside the app inside a GridView).

I have image paths coming in from a Web Service in the form of List, and would like to use that list of images to flip data bound item backgrounds inside the app.

I was unable to find anything online so I thought I'd ask here. If you know where to start with this please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use a user control which accept your list of pictures. And use a DispatcherTimer in your user control to switch/change your picture each X seconds.

Sample :

```
     public sealed partial class CustomFlip
    {
        #region Properties

        private readonly TimeSpan _delay = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        private readonly DispatcherTimer _dt;

        #endregion Properties

        #region Control Properties

        public IList<Uri> Pictures
        {
            get { return (IList<Uri>)GetValue(PicturesProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PicturesProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty PicturesProperty
            = DependencyProperty.Register("Pictures", typeof(IList<Uri>), typeof(CustomFlip), null);

        #endregion Control Properties

        public CustomFlip()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += CLoaded;
            _dt = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = _delay };
            _dt.Tick += Refresh;

            Unloaded += CUnloaded;
        }

        private void CLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _dt.Start();
        }

        private void CUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _dt.Stop();
        }

        private void Refresh(object sender, object e)
        {
            //Image name in your xaml.
            foo.Source = //Random Uri from Pictures.
//Sample this.MyImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/MyNameSpace;images/someimage.png", UriKind.Relative));
        }

        #region Methods

        public void StopRefresh()
        {
            _dt.Stop();
        }

        public void ReStartRefresh()
        {
            if (_dt == null)
                return;

            _dt.Start();
        }

        #endregion Methods
    }
```

And you xaml :

```
<UserControl
    x:Name="root"
    x:Class="Foo"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">
        <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="Image"/>
        </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

Regards.

Edit add xaml sample:

```
xmlns:flip="using:Project.CustomControls.CustomFlip" <!--FlipLocation-->
<flip:ControlName Pictures={Binding YourList}/> <!--Hw to use it-->
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the prompt reply. However, the code above does not work and has some missing arguments. Such as a return type on `EpgProgressBar` among other issues. Even when I fixed it up, I can't figure out how to properly use this. Do you have a working sample or something?

Comment: @user1027620 Hi, it's a working sample. I just missed to change EpgProgressBar by CustomFlip (it isn't a method but the constructor). It's a user control, so you need to call it from your page and give it your list (such as with other controls).

Comment: Thanks again, One more issue however is this line `get { return (Uri)GetValue(PicturesProperty); }` It expects a list `IList<System.Uri>` How should I change it?

Comment: Yes, again sorry. I forgot it.

Comment: Could you please share a sample on how to use the above user control in a XAML Page? Thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19879/discussion-between-david-and-user1027620)

Comment: Thanks David, will try this out tomorrow.